# JAVA Mouse Event

Tags: java, graphics, mouseevent, awt, mouseclick-event

In my program after selecting the option from pie menu related shape drawn around pie menu. what i want is when user select the option and then click anywhere in the screen related shape will draw there in the screen. can anyone tell me how can i achieve this? 

**Mouse click event code**

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    double base=x1-s;
    double prep=as-y1;
    double angle=Math.atan2(prep, base);
    angle=((angle*180)/Math.PI);

    if(angle==0)
    {

    }
    else if(angle>0&&angle<45)
    {

        p.mc1=e.getX()+100;
        p.mc2=e.getY()-25;
        p.repaint();        

    }
```

**Pie Menu**
**[image: Pie Menu Drawing]**

Comment: I dont see a question in your post, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Now for example after selecting the circle option circle will draw around pie menu. what i want is when user select the circle option and then click anywhere in the screen circle should draw there.

Comment: *"anywhere in the screen"*  Do you mean outside your application, or just in the 'drawing area' of the component?

Comment: @AndrewThompson just in the drawing area of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to make a shape exactly but a rectangle will help. Calculate the co-ordinates of each part of the pie chart and approximate it to a rectangle. For example, if the exit part in the pie chart is from (20,80), create a rectangle from (20,80) and width and height as 20 pixels.Create 9 rectangle objects like

> Rectangle r1=new Rectangle(int startX,int startY,int width,int height);

And using mouseListener, you can easily check which rectangle is selected by using

> ```
> public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
>     if(r1.contains(me.getPoint){
>          selected=1;
>     }
> ```

Use the selected value in a switch case and implement the methods for whatever u want to.